# LTE modem Fibocom L830-EB on ThinkPad T480s

Tags: release-loki

I install elementary OS on ThinkPad T480s. Everything works accept modem Fibocom Cat6 L830-EB 4G LTE.
I install "modem manager gui" and UI shows an error "Modem is not ready for operation. Please wait while modem is being prepared..."

[image]

I tried to do the same on linux mint 18.3 - the modem works.

Have somebody any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Kernel support and possible additional network manager packages or kernel modules might be somewhere to look. Perhaps there is more info if you search on the Ubuntu forums.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the firmware version of the [Fibocom cat6 L830-EB 4G LTE](https://www.4gltemall.com/fibocom-l830-eb.html) is not compatible with the OS.